# Trying to solve a system of 6 1st ODEs in python. Almost there but am getting errors

Tags: python

I just have place holders for the initial conditions. But it seems the `u` function is the main issue. In removing it and replacing it as a constant I get a float int error. I feel like I'm almost there and am just making a small mistake.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwbu0.png)

code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mpl.rc('text', usetex = True)
mpl.rc('font', family = 'serif', size=16)

from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

%matplotlib inline

def EulerSys(F, y0, ti, tf, h):
     t = np.arange(ti, tf+h, h)
     n = len(t)
     neq = len(y0)
     x = np.zeros((neq, n))
     x[:,0] = y0
     for i in range(t.size - 1):
         # [new value] = [old value] + [slope x step size]
         x[:,i+1] = x[:,i] + h*F( t[i], x[:,i] )
     return x

m1=55
m2=400
m3=100
k1=230000
k2=30000
k3=50000
k4=0
b2=1500
b3=4000
b4=700
L0=5
v=15
A=0.03
h = .05
ti =0 
tf =3.2
t = np.arange(ti, tf+h, h)
                     
# the initial conditions:
x0 = np.array([ 2.0, 0.0 , 1, 1,1,1])

n = len(t)
neq = len(x0)
# initialize the vector to store the solutions:
# the rows are the solutions, the columns are the time instances:
x = np.zeros((neq, n))
# store the initial conditions:
x[:,0] = x0
print(x)

def myFun(t,x):
    u = lambda t: (A/2)*(1-np.cos(2*(3.14*(v*t/L0)))
    n = len(x)
    dx = np.zeros((n))

    dx[0] = x[1]
    dx[1] = (-(b2 + b4)*x[1]+b2*x[3]+b4*x[5]-[k1+k2+k4]*x[0]+k2*x[2]+k4*x[4]+k1*u)/m1
    dx[2] = x[3]
    dx[3] = (b2*x[1]-(b2+b3)*x[3]+b3*x[5]+k2*x[0]-(k2+k3)*x[2]+k3*x[4])/m2
    dx[4] = x[5]
    dx[5] = (b4*x[1]+b3*x[3]-(b3+b4)*x[5]+k4*x[0]+k3*x[2]-(k3+k4)*x(4))/m3

    return dx

 xsol= EulerSys(myFun, x0, ti, tf, h)
```

Comment: it seems that you are just asking how to invoke a `lambda` function. Might be best to ask the question in this format:   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What is the problem/error you're having?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

you are simply missing one bracket at the end.

```
u = lambda t: (A/2)*(1-np.cos(2*(3.14*(v*t/L0)))
```

should be:

```
u = lambda t: (A/2)*(1-np.cos(2*(3.14*(v*t/L0))))  # one more bracket
```

here is the test code that is stripped from the original question:

```py
import numpy as np

# define variables needed
A = 1
v = 1
L0 = 1

u = lambda t: (A/2)*(1-np.cos(2*(3.14*(v*t/L0))))

print(u(1))
```

the result (with test numbers) is this:

```
2.536543312392503e-06
```

Comment: Please flag typo questions instead of answering them...

Comment: @Tomerikoo.  noted,  makes sense.